# Mongo $facet get and count the tags of the matched products in aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this aggregation pipeline:

```
 aggregate.lookup({
      from: 'tags',
      localField: 'tags',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'tags'
    });

aggregate.match({
      productType: 'product',
      available: true,
      categories: {
        $elemMatch: {
          url: '/category/test'
        }
      }
    });

aggregate.facet({
      products: [
        { $sort: { [order]: sort } },
        { $skip: skip },
        { $limit: pageSize },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            images: 1,
            onSale: 1,
            price: 1,
            quantity: 1,
            slug: 1,
            sale: 1,
            sku: 1,
            status: 1,
            title: 1,
            brand: 1,
            tags: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      tags: [
        { $unwind: '$tags' },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              name: '$name.label',
              slug: '$slug'
            },
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      range: [
        {
          $bucketAuto: {
            groupBy: '$price',
            buckets: 1,
            output: {
              min: { $min: '$price' },
              max: { $max: '$price' }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      total: [{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }]
    });

    aggregate.addFields({
      total: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$total', 0]
      }
    });

    aggregate.addFields({
      range: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$range', 0]
      }
    });
```

Every product has it's own tags and I can't figure out how to:

1. Get the tags that belong **only** to the matched products and return an array from the `$facet` that contains

```
tags: [{name: 'tag1', slug: 'slug1', count: 10}, {name: 'tag2', slug: 'slug2', count: 5} ]
```

Where `count: 10` are the products that have the tag.

Right now it returns all the tags found in the database.

<strike>2. Why the `range` property returns an object like this:</strike>

```
"range": {
            "_id": {
                "min": 5.9,
                "max": 47
            },
            "min": 5.9,
            "max": 47
        }
```

and not like this since i provide an `output` object in `$bucketAuto`:

```
"range": {
            "min": 5.9,
            "max": 47
        }
```

As of 2, this is normal mongodb behavior for `$bucketAuto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i've done and it works:

just right before `$facet`:

```
    aggregate.lookup({
      from: 'tags',
      let: { tags: '$tags' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$tags'] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'tags'
    });
```

and then inside `$facet`:

```
tags: [
        { $unwind: { path: '$tags' } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$tags',
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```